# Evaluate $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^2e^{\arctan x}}{\sqrt{{1+x^2}}}\ \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^2e^{\arctan x}}{\sqrt{{1+x^2}}}\ \mathrm{d}x$$

My try:

I tried substituting $x= \tan\theta$ and got,

$\displaystyle\int e^\theta \tan^2\theta \sec\theta\ \mathrm{d}\theta$ and cannot move forward. so I thought of finding two integrals($I$ and $J$)one of which is required and the other is taken such that $I+J, I-J$ are easy to find.but couldn't find such $J$ $\left(I=\displaystyle\int\frac{x^2e^{\arctan x}}{1+x^2}\ \mathrm{d}x\right)$

Also, I don't think I could make use of definite integral properties.

WolframAlpha result for the integral is

$\frac{(x-1)\sqrt{1+x^2}e^{arctanx}}{2}+C$

I also want to know how you got the idea for the solution.

Comment: How about using $u = -x$ to try to get rid of that unfriendly $\arctan x$?

Comment: @xbh but it is in power of e how can I get rid of that?

Comment: I haven't gone through the details, but have you tried by parts? $$u=xe^{\arctan(x)},dv=\frac{xdx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$ Looks like a wrap around integral.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong suggestion ×_×

Comment: @Matthew Pilling got it!! Thanks..why not answer so that the question can be left over other wise it will show up in 0 answers section

Comment: @Learner I don't think this works. Could you post your solution? Here's where I'm stuck: Let $$2I = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{2x^2e^{\arctan x}}{\sqrt{{1+x^2}}} dx$$
$$\begin{align}
2I &= \int_{-1}^1 \frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} xe^{\arctan x} dx\\
&= \left[2\sqrt{1+x^2}xe^{\arctan x} \right]^1_{-1} - \int_{-1}^1 2\sqrt{1+x^2} \left(e^{\arctan x} + \frac{xe^{\arctan x}}{1+x^2}\right) dx\\
&= \left[2\sqrt{1+x^2}xe^{\arctan x} \right]^1_{-1} - 2\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1+x^2} e^{\arctan x} dx - 2\int_{-1}^1 \frac{xe^{\arctan x}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\\
& = 2\sqrt 2 (e^{\pi/4} + e^{-\pi/4})  - ???
\end{align}$$

Comment: @MatthewPilling The last two integrals do not seem easy. I'm not sure though. Also, does not look like a wrap around integral unless I have made an error.

Comment: I think I got a solution. Let me type it out.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor I answered the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the integrand contains a factor of $e^{\arctan x}$ we expect the result to contain the same. Writing $$\frac{x^2e^{\arctan x}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=(e^{\arctan x}f(x))’$$ we obtain $(1+x^2)f’(x)+f(x)=x^2\sqrt{1+x^2}$. It is convenient to make the substitution $f(x)=g(x)\sqrt{1+x^2}$ as this will make the RHS a polynomial. This gives $$(1+x^2)g’(x)+(1+x)g(x)=x^2.$$ Consider the power series $g(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots$ so that $$x^2=(1+x^2)(a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+\cdots)+(1+x)(a_0+a_1+a_2x^2+\cdots).$$ Equating constant and linear terms gives $a_1=-a_0$ and $a_2=0$. Equating quadratic terms gives $a_3=(1+2a_0)/3$ with all higher-order coefficients being a constant multiple of $a_3$. Therefore, we have the general solution $$\int\frac{x^2e^{\arctan x}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,dx=e^{\arctan x}\sqrt{1+x^2}\left(a_0(1-x)+\frac{1+2a_0}3x^3h(x)\right)$$ where $h(x)$ is a power series. Taking $a_0=-1/2$ conveniently eliminates $h(x)$ and the result follows.

Comment: why did you take $f(x)=g(x)\sqrt{1+x^2}$.. I mean how did you get that idea

Comment: Its derivative being $g'(x)\sqrt{1+x^2}+xg(x)/\sqrt{1+x^2}$ means the $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ can be eliminated on both sides.

Comment: Ok so you wanted to eliminate that $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ and hence you did it right?

Comment: Yes. Eliminating the radical means I don't need to consider its series expansion which helps simplify the problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering beautiful method.."Learnt"

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $x=\tan t$
\begin{align}
I= \int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^2e^{\arctan x}}{\sqrt{{1+x^2}}}\ {d}x
&= \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} e^{t}\tan^2 t\sec t\>dt\\
&=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} e^{t}\sec t \> d(\tan t-1)
- \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} e^{t}\sec t \> dt\\
&= e^{t}\sec t (\tan t - 1) \bigg|_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}- I=\sqrt2e^{-\frac\pi4}
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry, how did you get to that $d(\tan t-1)$?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent - it is a shortcut to combine two steps

Comment: Oh. Which steps? I don't understand how you got from the first line to the second.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent - the integrand of the 2nd line is $e^t(\sec^3t - \sec t)$, which matches the 1st

Comment: I'm obviously being dense here, but how does $$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} e^{t}\sec t \> d(\tan t-1)=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} e^{t}\sec ^3t \> d t$$? To be honest I don't fully understand what the notation $d(\tan t-1)$ means.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent - note $d(\tan t-1) = d(\tan t) - d(1)= d(\tan t) $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123437/discussion-between-a-level-student-and-quanto).

Comment: @A-LevelStudent It's just saying $y = \tan t - 1 \implies dy = \sec^2tdt$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that:

$$(e^{\arctan(x)} \sqrt{1+x^2})' = \frac{e^{\arctan(x)}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} + \frac{xe^{\arctan(x)}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

$$x(e^{\arctan(x)}\sqrt{1+x^2})' = \frac{xe^{\arctan(x)}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} + \frac{x^2 e^{\arctan(x)}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Let us integrate the left-hand side. So, we have:

$$J = \int_{-1}^{1} x(e^{\arctan(x)}\sqrt{1+x^2})' \ dx = [x\sqrt{1+x^2}e^{\arctan(x)}]_{-1}^{1} - \int_{-1}^{1} e^{\arctan(x)} \sqrt{1+x^2} \ dx$$

Now, we have:

$$I = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{xe^{\arctan(x)}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \ dx$$

Let $u = e^{\arctan(x)}$ and $dv = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \ dx$. Then, $du = \frac{e^{\arctan(x)}}{1+x^2} \ dx$ and $v = \sqrt{1+x^2}$. So, we have that:

$$I = [\sqrt{1+x^2}e^{\arctan(x)}]_{-1}^{1} - \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{e^{\arctan(x)}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \ dx$$

Let the integral we want be denoted by $K$. Then:

$$K = J-I = 2\sqrt{2}e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}} + \int_{-1}^{1} -\frac{x^2e^{\arctan(x)}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \ dx$$

$$2K = 2\sqrt{2}e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

$$K = \sqrt{2}e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

as was desired. I initially had the idea of playing around with the product of $e^{\arctan(x)}$ and $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ because I basically observed that $\frac{x^2e^{\arctan(x)}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = x \cdot \frac{xe^{\arctan(x)}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and I had the idea that the second portion could be obtained by differentiating $e^{\arctan(x)}\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

I directly give the solution that give the indefinite integral. I solved this by using integration by parts. Let's call the indefinite integral $I$.

$$Let\; u=xe^{arctan(x)}\;,dv=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx.$$
We find
$$I=xe^{arctan(x)}(\sqrt{1-x^2})-\int\left(e^{arctan(x)}+\frac{xe^{arctan(x)}}{1+x^2}\right)\sqrt{1+x^2}\; dx$$
Again, by letting

$$u=e^{arctan(x)},dv=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$$
\begin{align}
I&=(x-1)\sqrt{1+x^2}e^{arctan(x)}-\int e^{arctan(x)}\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\\
&=(x-1)\sqrt{1+x^2}e^{arctan(x)}-I.
\end{align}
Then you get what you want by rearranging the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Matthew pilling's comment...

Take $u=xe^{arctanx}$,$v=\frac {x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

$I=xe^{arctanx}\sqrt{1+x^2}-\int (e^{arctanx}.1+\frac{x}{1+x^2})\sqrt{1+x^2}$

$\implies I=xe^{arctanx}\sqrt{1+x^2}-J.......(1)$

For $J$,I would like to take $e^{arctanx}\sqrt{1+x^2}.x=t$.now,

$dt=\frac{e^{arctanx}x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}+\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}+e^{arctanx}\sqrt{1+x^2}$

$dt= d(J+I)$

$\implies J=t-I$ substituting in equation $(1)$ we get the answer